# Can I inner join two DataTables where tableA.myColumn = tableB.myColumn?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable

I am parsing an Excel workbook and extracting the data into two DataTables like so:

```
If SetDBConnect("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & filepath & ";
Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1""", True) Then

'Get total dollars table
 sql.Append("SELECT * FROM [" & totalDollars & "]")
 dt = _dh.GetTable(sql.ToString())

sql.Length = 0
sql.Append("SELECT * FROM [" & totalUnits & "]")
dt_units = _dh.GetTable(sql.ToString())
End If
```

The two spreadsheets are exactly the same with one difference.  In the "Total Dollars" spreadsheet, there is a column with the dollar amounts, where in the "Total Units" spreadsheets, it is instead a column with unit amounts.

I would like to `INNER JOIN` these two tables `WHEN` the tableA.UPC = tableB.UPC.  Is this possible?  I have read about DataSets and DataRelations, but I was wondering if there was a simpler approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach using Linq would be:

```
var query = from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
            join r in dt_units.AsEnumerable() 
            on c.Filed<string>("UPC") equals r.Field<string>("UPC")
            select new {
                  UPC= r.Field<string>("UPC"),
                  //and so on.. you pick whatever columns you need from each table
            }
```

Comment: @user1496816 you shouldn't need anything special. If you are running this on .NET 3.5 you should be good.

Comment: Nevermind, the server actually does support .NET 3.5.  Also, is this in C#?  I use a C# to VB.NET converter, but it's not liking this code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't vote this up, but wanted to paste a VB .NET version:

```
Dim query = From c In dt.AsEnumerable() _
        Join r In dt_units.AsEnumerable() _
        On c.Field(Of String)("UPC") Equals r.Field(Of String)("UPC") _
        Select New With
        {
              .UPC = r.Field(Of String)("UPC")
        }
```